# Sakurai's explanation of degenerate electron gas

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am having some questions with the following equation of Sakurai's explanation electron gas.

Sakurai is trying to compute the ground state energy of the degenerate electron gas using perturbation theory. First he computes the Hamiltonian: [image]

Then he tries to compute the unperturbed Energy (for $H_0$) as follows:

[image]

What I don't get is the first line marked. First where is this weird $V/(2\pi)^3$ coming form? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I don't get is the two lines marked. First where is this weird
> $V/(2π)^3$ coming form?

It's a typical result in [density of states calculations in momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_states#Definition) (k) space. The momentum space states, when applying boundary conditions, are given by e.g. $k_x = \frac{2\pi}{L}$. In 3D, it's $(2\pi)^3/L^3$, where $L^3$ is the volume $V$.

> And secondly why is that when we take the sum over λ, we don't
> multiply the expression by 2 because of spin up and down?

You do.

The integral $\int_0^{k_F} \mathrm{d}^3k$ is the volume integral of a sphere of radius $k_F$, so it gives you $4\pi k_F^3/3$. Multiply by $2$ for spin degeneracy (the $\lambda$ sum), $8\pi k_F^3/3$.

The LHS pre-factor is $V/(2\pi)^3$, times the factor we just got, gives you $\frac{V}{3\pi^2}k_F^3$ as per the RHS.